# PHP change Array Format like first_name into First Name

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have array like in below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => agent_name
    [1] => first_name
    [2] => my_last_name
    [3] => job
    [4] => job_description
)
```

Now I want to convert this Array into below format.

```
Array
(
    'agent_name' => 'Agent Name',
    'first_name' => 'First Name',
    'my_last_name' => 'My Last Name',
    'job' => 'Job',
    'job_description' => 'Job Description',
)
```

So can anyone help me, how to set like this.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please. That should be more than nothing, even if you are still learning.

Comment: cf. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ especially 12, 13, 16 and 17

Comment: For clarification - do you just want to change the stored values of the array (i.e. having ['Agent Name', 'First Name', ...] in the end). Or do you want to convert an indexed array into a key-value store type of an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to replace the character `_` by space and then use the function [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) to uppercase the first letters of word.

```
<?php
$arr = array('agent_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'job', 'job_description');
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $new_arr[$val] = ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $val));
}
print_r($new_arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the combination of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to achieve this,

```
$a = array_combine($a,array_map(function($val) {
    return implode(' ',array_map('ucfirst',explode('_', $val)));
}, $a));

print_r($a);
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ebc117d7646b6c5740597a4eb1a55508bc45f8e).

Answer (score 0):

I used array_combine for this

```
$Main_Array =  array('agent_name','first_name','my_last_name','job','job_description');
$New_array =  array();
foreach ($Main_Array as $key => $value) {
 $New_array[] = ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$value));
}
$get_result = array_combine($Main_Array,$New_array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a simple foreach that works on the same array...

```
<?php

$data = array
(
    0 => 'agent_name',
    1 => 'first_name', 
    2 => 'my_last_name', 
    3 => 'job', 
    4 => 'job_description'
);

foreach ( $data AS $k => $v )
{
    $data[$v] = ucwords ( str_replace ( '_', ' ', $v ) );

    unset ( $data[$k] );
}

print_r ( $data );

?>
```